# Using existing media element instead of createMediaElement

Tags: vline

Is there an example of using an existing video element to attach the media streams rather than creating a new one with event.stream.createMediaElement()? I presume that's possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use an existing video or audio element (i.e. one that you created outside of vline) since the element returned from createMediaElement is tied to the stream inside the browser.  What you can do is have a div where you want to display the video, and replace the media element inside the div.